# Encoding base64 image string into JSON and decoding it back using jq

Tags: base64, jq

I have these 3 commands those work correctly and encode the image as json.

```
encoded_string=$(base64 volunteers.jpg)

payload="{\"instances\": [{\"image\": {\"b64\": \"$encoded_string\"}}]}"

echo $payload >input.json
```

But how do I convert it back to jpg format? This returns an error "**base64: invalid input**"

```
cat '/"' input.json '/"' | jq -r '.instances[0].image.b64' | base64 -d >output.jpg
```

Comment: FYI, you can use `jq` to create the JSON in the first place: `base64 volunteers.jpg | jq -R '{instances: [{image: {b64: .}}]}'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem most likely is due to the embedded newlines that that are created during the encoding part of the image. You can just remove them by using `tr -d \\n` in your original attempt which an be slightly re-written succinctly with inputs from `jq` capabilities to read from standard input.

```
jq -Rn '.instances[0].image.b64 = inputs' < <(base64 volunteers.jpg | tr -d \\n) > input.json
```

The `-n` part is to avoid `jq` reading a separate input stream of its own and `-R` for reading raw input. Here we feed the encoded content as if it were in a file using `bash` process substitution syntax `<(..)` and feed this created file to `jq`

and then decoding back the created JSON as

```
jq -r '.instances[0].image.b64' input.json | base64 -d > output.jpg
```

---

Re-writing your original attempt with minor enhancements and without using a temporary file for storing the JSON

```
JSON='{"instances": [{"image": {"b64": "'"$(base64 volunteers.jpg | tr -d \\n)"'" }}]}'
jq -r '.instances[0].image.b64' <<<"$JSON" | base64 -d >output.jpg
```

or use `printf()` inplace of the here-strings(`<<<`)

```
printf '%s\n' "$JSON" | jq -r '.instances[0].image.b64' | base64 -d >output.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks. Just making sure that your command will generate the same json file as per this blog post... https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/adding-ai-to-your-applications-with-ready-to-use-models-from-aws-marketplace/

Answer (score 1):

The invocation

```
cat '/"' input.json '/"'
```

is hopelessly muddled: `cat input.json` would suffice.  Even better, assuming input.json contains valid JSON, you could write:

```
< input.json jq -r '.instances[0].image.b64' | base64 -d >output.jpg
```